# Get X and Y coordinate of cell in table

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I generate table using itextsharp and I would like to retreive the rectangle coordinate of a specific cell in the table. I can't find a way to acheive this.
 
Let say I have a table with 3 columns and 3 rows. I would like to retreive the rectangle coordinate of the middle cell on second row. The table is added using columnText with AddElement.
From what I can see, I can get the Y or X for the table element once added to the document, but I can't find an easy way to get the rectangle coordinate of a specific cell. Any hint?

Comment: Considering Joris' answer: do you generate the table and want the coordinates while still generating that very pdf? Or did you generate the table before, have saved the pdf, have reloaded it in a PdfReader, and now want the coordinates?

Comment: hi mkl, yes i generate the table and want the coordinates while still generating that pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is similar to
[I am given a pdf file which has tabular data in it. I need to extract the data according to the given condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41563241/i-am-given-a-pdf-file-which-has-tabular-data-in-it-i-need-to-extract-the-data-a)

To answer your question, there is no easy way (in most cases). And without a reference pdf document, it is hard to answer your question in more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, once the table is built, i have  information on each cell rectangle (width, height, llx, lly, ...). I have to calculate the X/Y of left bottom border of rectangle of the cell after adding the table in columntext.

Comment: Joris, as clarified by the OP in a comment to the question, the problem is different from the one you refer to.

Answer (score 0):

I answering my question : IPdfPCellEvent is the key.